# Connecting with TCPS - ora-28759: failure to open file

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using below code to connect the Oracle DB.

```
dsn_tns='(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcps)(HOST =hostdetails)(PORT =port))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = servicename)))'

conn = cx.connect(user=USER, password=PW, dsn=dsn_tns)
print(cx.version)
```

Comment: platform.platform: Darwin-18.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
sys.maxsize > 2**32: True
platform.python_version: 3.7.4
cx_Oracle.version: 7.3.0
cx_Oracle.clientversion: (19, 3, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: please let me know if i need to add any other files

Comment: As it is TCPS protocol.I have add the sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora in the path ⁨instantclient_19_3⁩ \⁨network⁩\admin. now I am geting new error ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Comment: try debugging the connection problem using http://1stoporacledebug.blogspot.com/2011/09/oracle-database-10g-debugging.html